# Is the Usage "I are" proper English?

Tags: word-usage, agreement, literary-english

So I'm reading a 19th-century novel called The Count of Monte Cristo, and I came across this particular usage, which is:

[H]e continued," let us make all possible speed. I are most anxious to finish my evening at the Duke of Bracciano's."

I'm aware some usages in the book tend to be rather old-fashioned, but I still find the use of "I are" very peculiar. Is this a common usage in older English or in literary works? Thanks.

Comment: As this novel was originally written in French, it could be a mistake in translation or a deliberate mistake reflecting intentionally bad grammar in the original. But it is not correct.

Comment: Old engineering school joke:  Four years ago I couldn't even spell "injunere", and now I are one.

Comment: The French is *Maintenant, monsieur le comte, dit-il, la plus grande diligence possible! je tiens énormément à aller finir ma nuit chez le duc de Bracciano.* I don't believe there are any grammatical mistakes in the French.

Comment: I’m voting to close because there are just two results for: [I are "most anxious to finish my evening"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk017IBK-ifqrm5OusZ8aD4155cAZdg%3A1597274545173&ei=sXk0X9CMCsjTkgWb1buACA&q=I+are+%22most+anxious+to+finish+my+evening%22&oq=I+are+%22most+anxious+to+finish+my+evening%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoFCCEQoAE6BAghEApQos0BWODhAWCA6AFoAHABeACAAYABiAGVCZIBAzcuNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiQqf6u55brAhXIqaQKHZvqDoAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: [added]: only two results on Google strongly suggest the plural verb cited " I are most anxious" is a typographical error (a typo).

Comment: @PeterShor's citation of the French shows the corresponding words as "je tiens énormément", which is both correct French and properly singular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not common usage in older English. I think it's a misprint. The 1888 edition has "I am enormously anxious to finish my night at the Duke of Bracciano’s.”

If it isn't a misprint it could conceivably be a device of the translator's, to portray the speaker as affected (artificial, pretentious).

In French, 'Je sommes' certainly has its uses. Evidently this isn't one of them.

Comment: It could also be an OCR error.  ’m’ and ’re’ could look similar.

Comment: @Jim: Or 'm' and 'rn' look similar, and an automatic spelling corrector fixed "arn" to "are". Automation is getting so complicated there is room for more and more complicated mistakes.

Comment: @PeterShor -  Oh, good thought!

Answer (score 0):

The conjugation of the verb "to be" is:

I am

thou art (archaic)

you (singular) are

he/she is

we are

you (plural) are

they are

From this viewpoint, the use of "I are" is neither a matter of usage nor of choice. It is simply wrong.